# Rails Simple form button id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I can't get the id to work in simple form on a button, I've tried

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202142/manually-set-the-ids-of-form-input-fields-in-a-simpleform-form)

```
= f.button, :input_html => { :id => 'my_id' }
= f.button, :input_html => { :id => 'my_id' }, :submit
```

[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953324/change-id-in-simple-form)

```
= f.button, html: { id: :edit_account } 
= f.button, html: { id: :edit_account } :submit
```

What's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`= f.button :submit, id: "whatever"`

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#buttons), it accepts an optional string and an options hash (for class or id). Internally, it simply calls the `submit_tag` helper and that's why it's different from the `input` helper where you pass any HTML attributes in the `input_html` hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`= f.button :submit, input_html: { id: 'edit_account' }`

From docs:

> If you want to pass the same options to all inputs in the form (for example, a default class), you can use the :defaults option in simple_form_for. Specific options in input call will overwrite the defaults:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, input_html: { maxlength: 20 } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { value: '1' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

> Since Simple Form generates a wrapper div around your label and input by default, you can pass any html attribute to that wrapper as well using the :wrapper_html option, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, wrapper_html: { class: 'username' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, wrapper_html: { id: 'password' } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, wrapper_html: { class: 'options' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The `button` helper passes the option hash as-is to the `submit_tag` helper and it won't work with an `input_html` hash. It will output an `input_html` attribute.

Comment: Rails 5 :| -  <%= form.button :submit, id: 'submit_admin_course_' + i.to_s %>