# Simple Form ID not being detected in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using the simple form gem in my ruby on rails app. In my app, I'm also using ActiveStorage to hold images.

I'm using `Krajee` jquery file-input

I want to be able to upload images using the simple form gem. Here is my input:

```
<%= f.input :image, input_html: { id: :image_input } %>
```

I'm supposed to initialize the input using this command (as provided by the docs)

```
<script>

  $(function() {

        // initialize with defaults
        $("#image_input").fileinput();

        // with plugin options
       $("#image_input").fileinput({'showUpload':false, 'previewFileType':'any'});

  });

</script>
```

The jquery code is not hiding the input. I have checked if jQuery is installed and made sure that it was working. I imagine that the problem lies somewhere in the way I'm creating my input field, but I'm not too sure.

Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE***

When I check the page source, the input does have the correct id, however, the style of the input is set to `display: none`. I'm guessing that has something to do with the Krajee Library.

I tried this post: [Change id in simple form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953324/change-id-in-simple-form)

it did not work.

Comment: Have you checked the HTML to see if it really contains `<input type="image" id="image_input">`?

Comment: It is there, let me update question because the input itself is not being displayed.

Comment: I don't use RoR, so I'm not making this an answer. But I suspect it should be `<%= f.input :image,  id: "image_input" %>`

Answer (score 0):

try keeping the id as string instead of symbol
something like this

```
html: {class: "form-horizontal quote-form", id: "send-quote-form", :multipart => true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initialize with defaults
    $("#image_input").fileinput();

    // with plugin options
    $("#image_input").fileinput({'showUpload':false, 'previewFileType':'any'});
})
```

Comment: dang it, this also didn't work :/ Thank you though, I'll keep researching.